# pandas argsort how to leave nan as nan?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Suppose `sr` is a `pandas.Series`, then unlike `sr.mean()` or `sr.std()` which skips `nan` *and* leaves them intact in the output, `sr.argsort()` will use `-1` to indicate where `nan` are present. But I don't want this conversion. I simply want `argsort` to work exactly like `mean` or `std` i.e. does not change `nan` values to `-1`. Unfortunately `argsort` doesn't have a `skipna` parameter. What can I do?

PS I know I can replace `-1` with `nan` but this is a bit clumsy.

---

Example:

```
sr = pd.Series(data=[2,0.5,99,np.nan])
sr
Out[61]: 
0     2.0
1     0.5
2    99.0
3     NaN
dtype: float64
expected_sort = sr.argsort().replace(-1, np.nan)
expected_sort
Out[63]: 
0    1.0
1    0.0
2    2.0
3    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current approach isn't bad...

Here are some alternatives

**Alt 1**

```
sr.argsort().mask(sr.isnull())

0    1.0
1    0.0
2    2.0
3    NaN
dtype: float64
```

---

**Alt 2**

```
sr.dropna().argsort().reindex_like(sr)

0    1.0
1    0.0
2    2.0
3    NaN
dtype: float64
```

---

**Alt 3**
*AKA overkill*

```
pd.Series(
    np.where(
        np.isnan(sr.values),
        np.nan, sr.values.argsort()
    ), sr.index)

0    1.0
1    0.0
2    2.0
3    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yes, if there were to be any alternative not involving `replace`, it would be this.

Comment: Alt 3 works well with Numba and is faster when vectorized.